# Drupal Commons 7.x 3.9 misses "Create a Post" on front page

Tags: 7

I am not sure what happened, but I seem to have lost the "Create a Post" item at the top of the "What's going on?" default front page. I did not consciously delete it.

I compared the site missing "Create A Post" with another site having it, but I cannot find any difference.

Any troubleshooting help much appreciated.

Comment: What changes did you make before it disappeared?

Comment: Nothing I am aware of.  It was there, and then next time I looked it was gone.  I did not install any modules or make any configuration changes.  ???